# How do I read consecutive lines of input from the console to use for an Add() method?

Tags: c#, methods, console-application, readline

The following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace JeffOrrisSimpleCalculator._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Simple Calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("\t1> Add");
            Console.WriteLine("\t2> Subtract");
            Console.WriteLine("\t3> Multiply");
            Console.WriteLine("\t4> Divide");
            Console.WriteLine("\t5> Quit");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Selection:  ");

            string myValue = ValidateData();
            Console.WriteLine(myValue);

            Console.Write("Enter number one:  ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter number two:  ");
            Console.ReadLine();

            string mySum = Add();
            Console.WriteLine(mySum);

            Console.Read();
        }//end main

        private static string ValidateData()
        {


            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if ((temp == "1") || (temp == "2") || (temp == "3") || (temp == "4") ||                (temp == "5"))
            {
                //string Response = "Thank You";
                //return Response;

                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                string Response = "Please enter a valid selection";
                return Response;

            }
        }//end ValidateData



        private static string Add()
        {
            string numberOne = Console.ReadLine();
            double temp1 = Convert.ToDouble(numberOne);

            string numberTwo = Console.ReadLine();
            double temp2 = Convert.ToDouble(numberTwo);

            double total = temp1 + number2;
            string myTotal = Convert.ToString(total);
            return myTotal;
        }


        }//end class
        }//end namespace
```

*Im just concerned with the add method.  Im prompting the user to enter 2 numbers that I need to add using the add method.  I believe im over-thinking this.  I am used to windows forms and not console apps.  I can't figure out how to consecutively save these input variable from Console.ReadLine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Im prompting the user to enter 2 numbers

Yes, you're prompting the user - but then you're completely ignoring their input. This:

```
Console.Write("Enter number one:  ");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter number two:  ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

should probably be more like:

```
Console.Write("Enter number one:  ");
string firstLine = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter number two:  ");
string secondLine = Console.ReadLine();
```

Next you need to work out how to convert the *strings* into *numbers*. Look at [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/f02979c7.aspx) and the like for that step.

(You may want to validate "number one" before asking for "number two" - consider creating a method which takes a prompt string and keeps prompting the user until they actually enter a number - which is then returned from the method.)

Comment: Thank man...Ive been up all night burnt out.  I didn't realize I had to declare readline variable after every time prompting the user. I can finish now with my other methods.  I can't upvote you because I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: @JeffOrris: Well you don't have to declare a different variable each time - but the return value from the method is the line the user entered. You just have to use that however you want to :)